# javascript auto time difference function only working for first row of a dynamically created table rows

Tags: javascript, html

trying to calculate time difference between two input time for dynamically cloned table row. but the JavaScript is only showing the time difference for the very first row. rest are not calculating automatically.

i have tried defining the class for it. still not working

```js
function cloneRow() {
  var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone");
  var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
  var tags = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  var len = tags.length;
  var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "row_" + len;
  clone.id = "newID";
  table.appendChild(clone);
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
  try {
    var table =
      document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
      var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
      if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
        if (rowCount <= 2) {
          alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
          break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}

function pad(num) {
  return ("0" + num).slice(-2);
}

function diffTime(start, end) {
  var s = start.split(":"),
    sMin = +s[1] + s[0] * 60,
    e = end.split(":"),
    eMin = +e[1] + e[0] * 60,
    diff = eMin - sMin;
  if (diff < 0) {
    sMin -= 24 * 60;
    diff = eMin - sMin
  }
  var h = Math.floor(diff / 60),
    m = diff % 60;
  return "" + pad(h) + " hrs:" + pad(m) + " min";
}

function change() {
  window.document.getElementById('delay').value = diffTime(
    window.document.getElementById('timeOfCall').value,
    window.document.getElementById('timeOfResponse').value
  );
}
```

```html
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="cloneRow()" />
<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
<br><br>
<table id="dataTable" border=1>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Start Time</th>
    <th>End Time</th>
    <th>Duration</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="rowToClone">
    <TD>
      <INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk" />
    </TD>
    <td><input type="datetime" name="stime" placeholder="hrs:mins" value="hh:mm" id="timeOfCall"></td>
    <td><input type="datetime" name="etime" placeholder="hrs:mins" value="hh:mm" id="timeOfResponse"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="delay" class="value" onclick="change(this.value)"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

want to auto calculate the time for the particular row when clicked on the duration box of the respective row

Comment: You are overwriting clone.id with 'newID' on every row.

Comment: thanks for your reply. please suggest me the appropriate changes for the desired result

Comment: delete this: clone.id = "newID"

Comment: Deleted the same. Still the function is calculating the time difference for the first row only and not the dynamically added rows.

Comment: Why do you think that is?

Comment: sorry. i didn't understand. can you please suggest the desired changes in the code